# WP-REST API excluding category doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

I used this [semi-official plugin](http://v2.wp-api.org/) to enable API call.

But I can't find a way to exclude category. For example if I have `mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category__not_in]=10`, it will ignores the filter and show all latest posts.

Is there a way to exclude category from the API call?

Comment: Can't you upgrade to 4.4? The Rest API is part of the core now.

Comment: @vard Oh I already upgraded to 4.4, but I think it still needs the plugin.

Comment: Mmh it shouldn't, do you have any error when you deactivate it and try to use the rest api? (I'm not sure if by default it use the 2.0 or 1.0 version of the API, but it can be set through the config)

Comment: I just tested and it doesn't work without plugin. But going to `mysite.com/wp-json/` gives json about my site name, description. I think 4.4 added filter that allow plugin to easily create json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Rest API some filters are available only for logged in users:

> In addition, the following are available when authenticated as a user
>   with `edit_posts`:
>
> [...]
>
> `category__not_in`

This is taken from the [Rest API 1.0 documentation](http://wp-api.org/#posts_retrieve-posts).

What that mean is you need to logged in as an editor (user with `edit_posts` capability). For doing this in a clean way, I suggest create a minimal role for REST user with only the capabilities you need, something like this:

```
add_role(
    'rest_user',
    __( 'REST User' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true,
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'delete_posts' => false
    )
);
```

Then do your query as authenticated user with the following:

```
$response = wp_remote_request('http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[category__not_in]=10', array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode('login:password')
    )
));
```

Thanks to [this article](https://1fix.io/blog/2015/02/28/wordpress-rest-api-media/) you shared, it seems you need to declare the filter name as query var, so in this case:

```
add_filter('query_vars', function($query_vars) {
    $query_vars[] = 'category__not_in';
    return $query_vars;
});
```

Which make sense because Wordpress is droping any GET parameter that isn't declare, though I don't understand why all the filters are not declared as query vars inside the WP Core...

Comment: I already logged in as admin and when I go directly to the URL, it still shows all unfiltered latest post. Maybe it's bug with v2?

Comment: Maybe - the text I quoted is from the v1 doc - I don't see any reference to this filter values in the v2 doc. I suggest to give it a try with the 1.0 version and see if it help.

Comment: I put a bug report in their repo and got [the same answer](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1884#issuecomment-166351516). Let's wait for their next reply.

Comment: Could you try with an other auth filter like `offset` and see if it works? It would help to know if it's a auth problem or something specific to `category__not_in` filter.

Comment: All variable that is under "must be authenticated" doesn't seem to work. I used the same browser to directly access the json URL, so I should have been authenticated right?

Comment: I just got the answer from [this post](https://1fix.io/blog/2015/02/28/wordpress-rest-api-media/). I put `$query_vars[] = 'category__not_in';` and it works. Thanks a lot for your time :). You can edit your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Ah very good to know. I updated my answer to add info about this. Though I feel like this is a bit redundant, Wordpress should add those query vars himself...

Answer (score -2):

For WP API V2 use a minus sign, for example:

```
http://yourwpwebsite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/&filter[cat]=1,2,-3
```

will retrieve all posts in categories with id= 1 and id = 2 but excluding any posts in category with id= 3